# how to update with a select without where condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to remove the first sign on all of my query results, which works.
However I don't know how to update all tables at once without using the where condition.

My request

```
'SELECT Revenue FROM `film`'
```

works and displays the following results:

```
Revenue
$108,300,000.00
$69,400,000.00
$131,900,000.00
$201,500,000.00
```

My request :

```
'SELECT SUBSTR(Revenue, 2, length(Revenue)) FROM film'
```

also works and displays the following results:

```
SUBSTR(Revenue, 2, length(Revenue))
108,300,000.00
69,400,000.00
131,900,000.00
201,500,000.00
```

My request :

```
'update table film
set Revenue = SUBSTR(Revenue, 2, length(Revenue)) '
```

is not working. Thank you Louisdefunes

Comment: When you say "It's not working", do you get an error, or nothing happens?

Comment: If that request is not working, TELL US WHY. What is the error message?

Comment: Instead of "update table film" try "update film"

Comment: Thank you Deniz, it's worked

Comment: You want to update ALL tables or just Film? Because you would need a stored procedure for that.

Answer (score -1):

What error message do you get?

Can you try this and tell me what happens?

```
update film
set Revenue = SUBSTR(Revenue, 2, length(Revenue));
```

See: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: update film instead of update table film is working, thank you